# Route webserver on 8080 through another webserver on port 80

Tags: web-server, redirect, port

I have a local webserver that is mapped to port 80 (Windows, XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and a domain "mydomain.com" that directs to the local webserver's IP. Everything works nicely. Now I'm trying to set up another program with an inbuilt webserver that runs on port 8080.

Ideally I don't want to expose both port 80 & port 8080 on my router to this machine. I could, but what I want to do is enter mydomain.com/application or app.mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com:8080. Nice and clean, that way only port 80 needs to be forwarded. I have no idea how to do this or if it's even possible.

Open to all suggestions & apache/htaccess/php/perl/port forwarding tricks. My googlefu fails me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure a [Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/) for your app.
Within this one you can configure a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks like exactly what I need - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just switch the ports? Let xampp run on port 8080 and the other webserver on port 80.

Comment: My aim is to only have 1 port open, thanks for the reply though!